# Getting error while updating tools from Android SDK Manager

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I should update Android SDK Tools and Android SDK Platform-tools from Android SDK Manager. I accepted the licence terms and updating was started. But an error was occured and said me that;

---

The following processes:

- cmd.exe
- java.exe

are locking the following directory:

C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\tools

Please close these applications so that the installation can continue.

When ready, press YES to try again.

---

I opened the Task Manager and killed these processes. As you might guess, when i have killed these processes, Android SDK Manager closed. If you kill java.exe process, SDK Manager was also killed. This is a weird error description and not show you the right solution way. How can i update that Tools? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have same problem earlier,then i delete the current Android sdk and install it once again.Hope this work for you too.

Comment: It is the last resort for me. I am trying to find another solution. Eclipse is sometimes annoying me. I am trying to understand him or her whatever :)

Comment: great..Why don't you restart your system so that if some internal file is open .then that will be closed.

Comment: I tried that, but same problem continues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps:

Close the sdk manager and eclipse.

Go to the folder where you have stored your adt.

In that adt folder you'll find a folder known as tools.

Make a copy of the contents of that folder and paste it in a folder called copytools.

Now go to the command prompt and go to the location of the copytools.

Then execute the command android.bat the sdk manager will start.

Now update all the plugins you want. It'll update your original folder.

After the update delete the copy.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by copying my `\tools` folder, naming the copy `\toolsCopy`. Then I ran `android.bat` from the `\toolsCopy` folder with Administrator privileges.

Running the SDK manager from `\tools` locked the renaming of the `\tools` directory, for obvious reasons. SMH

Thanks it works